# ASP .Net Core Call Controller Function from Javascript with redirect from Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am breaking my head on this and cant find a solution. In short I have a ASP .Net Core MVC page that has a Javascript list. I need to pass that list to a redirect. I have this in place and it is working so not the solution I am looking for as it is not secure.

So what I am trying to do is calling the Controller function from Javascript passing the list. I can only do this with Ajax but the controller wont redirect on an Ajax call. Is there anyone that has encountered a similar problem and possibly a solution for this?

Javascript var -> Controller -> redirect.

Thank you in advance guys

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a redirect on ajax call return (for example, by using [Jquery ajax success setting](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can implement some code at the return of a call really easily), or do you absolutely have to redirect with C# ?

Comment: I kind of need to redirect from C# as I ned to pass a model to the page that is generated based on the list that was sent from the initial javascript list. I have started looking at the following but not much luck eg: window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Sandbox")' + list;

Comment: Could you add in the question what you have tried so far? This is to prevent comment / answers with solutions that you already tried

Comment: I have searched for: 
asp net core window location href with parameters asp.net mvc best results but not working as expected

Comment: window.location.href ="Sandbox/Index?test=" + 'My test string'   This code sends a single string as expected. I want to send a list. So a dirty solution would be to add list items to string and coma delimit. But is that the best solution?

Comment: Sorry I've been unclear, when you say in your question **but the controller wont redirect on an Ajax call**, what have you tried so far on C# side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. So leaving the answer here for any future guys having the same problem.

Javascript

```
    $("#btn").click(function () {
       var PostData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
       if (PostData != "") {            
          window.location.href ="Controller/Function?test=" + PostData
                   
       } else
         alert('Oops.!!');});
```

C# Controller

```
 public IActionResult Test(string test)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("function", "Controller", new { test });
    }
```

Comment: Well done! Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: This is the most acceptable answer in the world.

Comment: Can only accept my answer in 2 days, its a bit silly but will remember to do so. Thank you guys